# Can't Display Table Headers in Responsive table layout

Tags: css, html

Am using below mentioned code to display table in WordPress post. It displayed table correctly, but I want to make to responsive so, I used custom CSS code to make Responsive table layout. It's working but missing table headers while resizing page layout. can anyone please guide me.

```
$menu .= '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>';
while ( have_rows('sections_items') ) : the_row();
    // Your loop code
    $menu .= '<tr><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_names').'</td><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_description').'</td><td>$ '.get_sub_field('dish_price').'</td></tr>';
endwhile;
$menu .= '</table> ';
```

/* CSS code*/

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

/* end of css*/ Here is the out of table am getting

[image]